# Super Annoying Button Behavior in Eclipse Form Widgets

Tags: android, eclipse, button, formatting

I'm trying to lay down 16 buttons in 4 rows of 4 for a calculator app using small buttons under form widgets.

The first row of 4 buttons snap together with no problem, but once I get to the 2nd row, they become stubborn and start moving to places I don't want them...I also notice a bunch of green, sensitive arrows while I hover with the button waiting to place it.

Any ways to make this an easier process? I literally cannot lay 16 buttons down where I want them.

Comment: Please post your xml layout. I'm pretty sure your're new to Android so I suggest you take a look at [android layouts](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html)

Comment: I don't know what layout you are using, but I think you should use a **TableLayout**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to solve this depend on your parent Layout:

1) If you have "n" Linearlayout, You can asign a same weigth value to each button.

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1
    ... />
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html

2) If you are using a Relative Layout only setting your aligns properties (and be patient with your eclipse)

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html

3) Use a GridLayout

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Comment: Thank you kindly...I've added a table layout with table rows and it works magically.